# Flex: How to embed fonts with CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textfield

I have two questions:

I am trying to embed fonts via [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_01.html) in the livedocs.

- Can anyone tell me what I need to do to use an external style sheet? *Should* it be a style sheet or an mxml file?
  I saw [this tutorial](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=40), which offers quite a bit of good information (some of which I also found in the livedocs) via the comments.

**EDIT: here is what I am trying...**

I have a class that I instantiate:

```
private var myTextDraw:TextSpriteDraw = new TextSpriteDraw();
```

How can I let this class use the font I have just embedded?  See below for details on what I am trying...

Here is how I am attempting to call up the mxml file:

```
<mx:Style source="..assets/fontSpecifications.mxml" />
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- specification for how to embed fonts -->

<mx:Application xmlns: mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Style>

        @font-face: {
            src: url("location") | local("name");
            fontFamily: 'myTimesFont', "_serif";
            color: black;
            fontStyle: normal;
            fontWeight: normal;
            advancedAntiAliasing: false;
        }

    </mx:Style>

    <mx:Script>
        [ Embed(source='../assets/Times.dfont', fontName='myTimesFont', mimeType='application/x-font') ] 
    </mx:Script>
<mx:Application>
```

Now what I don't understand is how to use the font that I have embedded (or if I am even doing this properly... note that all i want to do is get a TextField() w/ 'Times' to behave properly when I change its alpha):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external style sheet can be used by doing `<mx:Style source="my/css/Style.css" />`

On the second question I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you wondering if you should use the Flex Framework or a pure AS3 project? Or the tools in the Flash IDE versus Flex Builder for dealing with fonts?

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: ok; i don't need anything in the contents of the mx:Style tag then? can i include everything in the style sheet and then use an embed tag?...  
regarding your question- i am wondering about the latter- should i use the tools involved in the flash ide vs. the tools in flex builder for dealing with fonts?

Comment: @ryan: I have updated my question to show you what I am trying to do; I have included all of the relevant source and more specific questions for how to do this in Flex.

Comment: okay, I got it. So you won't use an MXML page as the source of the stylesheet, you'll just use a CSS file which would contain the stuff you have in your < mx:Style > tag in the second bit of code.

Then in your main application you can use the < mx:Script > tag with the embed metadata to embed that font.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so.  I will give it a try, do some research based on what you are suggesting, and post back if necessary.  I'm sure that this is enough information, but it's a bit of a new topic for me so I am assuming this will be what I need to get over the curve.

Comment: Feel free to drop me an email or ping me on IM if that helps. gtalk:ryanstewart82@gmail.com and aol:rcstewart82